# wmi c# - WMI Giving Incorrect Voltage Readings

Tags: c#, wmi

So I made a program with WPF, C# and WMI as a small project to gather the specifications of a computer, and put it on SourceForge because it was of little use to me.
I soon discovered that SoftPedia had picked it up, and noticed in their screenshot that there was an error with the voltage reading. This is an image nicked from their page:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QpBq.png

At the moment I source the voltage by using "CurrentVoltage", e.g.

```
foreach (var item in new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_Processor").Get())
{
    labelName.Content = (decimal.Parse(item["CurrentVoltage"].ToString()) / 10).ToString() + " v";
}
```

As you can see in the image, it's reading as 0v in the picture. I was wondering if I would need to switch "CurrentVoltage" to "VoltageCaps", or if I would need to do something like reading the SMBIOS directly.

If the latter, please specify how to do so, thanks.

Comment: Please indent your code with four spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the documentation for the [Win32_Processor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394373%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class:

> Voltage of the processor. If the eighth bit is set, bits 0-6 contain the voltage multiplied by 10. If the eighth bit is not set, then the bit setting in VoltageCaps represents the voltage value. CurrentVoltage is only set when SMBIOS designates a voltage value.

This means that if it reads as `0` when masked with `0x80`, then you should use the value from `VoltageCaps` to 'state' the voltage as one of the 3 listed values for `VoltageCaps`, unless the result of querying is `NULL`, in which case the voltage is unknown.

Comment: Is there any other method, using C#, to get the voltage?

Comment: Nothing obvious springs to mind; sorry! I'm used to accessing the IPMI/Raw sensor data from C++ which tends to be the origin of all the readings that appear in the WMI information

Comment: This may sound stupid, but would it be possible to use C++ in C#, perhaps using a DLL in C++ and referencing it in C#? If the previous was possible, and I did it, would there be an error like in the provided picture?