# c# / c / c++ / assembly - Retrieving Voltage Information?

Tags: c#, wmi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [wmi c# - WMI Giving Incorrect Voltage Readings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553381/wmi-c-sharp-wmi-giving-incorrect-voltage-readings)

Firstly, is it possible to use C, C++ or Assembly DLLs with C#?
If it is, would I simply add a reference to this DLL, or would I have to P/Invoke it?

Now, onto the main question.
I have noticed that, when using WMI with C# to retrieve information, on certain architectures and processors the information is either completely inaccurate, or is simply not there. I was wondering if, should the above question be possible, using C, C++ or Assembly would yield better results.
If it would, what I need write, how would I need to write it, and, if using assembly, how would I compile it into a DLL? Thanks for any answers.

WMI does not provide "CurrentVoltage" or "VoltageCaps"
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GJ8E.jpg

Comment: You can call C/C++ code in various ways, such as using a COM interface, a managed C++ (C++/CLI) DLL, or by using P/Invoke.

Comment: *When using WMI with C# to retrieve information, on certain architectures and processors the information is either completely inaccurate, or is simply not there.* Well, that might be a problem with the WMI provider, not with the language you're using to query it. Can you elaborate on that missing or inaccurate information?

Comment: When using C# with WMI, and querying the processor for "CurrentVoltage" I have noticed that on Sandybridge and Yorkfield architectures the voltage comes up as null or 0. On another processor, using the Penryn architecture, voltage came up as 3.3v.

Comment: There is an interesting discussion about that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8553420/608772)

Comment: @JPBlanc, ah, that's a dupe then. Nice catch :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your problem comes from the language you're using to query WMI.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394373.aspx) for the `CurrentVoltage` property says:

> Voltage of the processor. If the eighth bit is set, bits 0-6 contain
>   the voltage multiplied by 10. If the eighth bit is not set, then the
>   bit setting in **VoltageCaps** represents the voltage value.
>   **CurrentVoltage** is only set when [SMBIOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_BIOS) designates a voltage value.

So, querying the `VoltageCaps` property on the Sandy Bridge / Yorkfield systems (since `CurrentVoltage`'s eighth bit is not set) should solve your problem.

Comment: Quite same answer as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8553420/608772)

Comment: Yup, I did not see the duplicate before you mentioned it. I'm split between deleting this or leaving it, since I voted to close the question as a dupe anyway.

Comment: This question is not about it giving incorrect results, but more about how to retrieve said information using a different, lower-down, language. Also, using VoltageCaps does not work.

Comment: @Liam, that's interesting. What does `VoltageCaps` return?

Comment: VoltageCaps returns a blank space. You can see that illustrated in this picture: http://i.imgur.com/nNc8C.jpg

Comment: @Liam, strange... It looks like `VoltageCaps` is blank because it's not applicable (the other `Get-WmiObject` dumps I could find on Google always have either `CurrentVoltage` or `VoltageCaps` blank). It might indeed be a problem with the WMI provider if `CurrentVoltage` is supposed to be meaningful.

Comment: Which brings us conveniently back round to the main question. Would I be likely to see a correct answer when using C/C++/Assembly and, if so, how would I go about retrieving this information? I couldn't find or think of another method to retrieve this information other than using a low-level language and harnessing C#'s ability to run unmanaged code, such as this http://bit.ly/uB27Vt.

Comment: I still don't think using a lower-level language would change anything, but I might be wrong. If the problem comes from the PowerShell formatter, maybe creating a simple C# application using `SelectQuery` and `ManagementObjectSearcher` would be sufficient.

Comment: I tried using ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_Processor") but to no avail. It still returns 0 and null for CurrentVoltage and VoltageCaps respectively.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the WMI provider. Can you update your question with this information and the PowerShell screenshot you've taken? This will show it's not a dupe, so others will vote to reopen it.